# bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml, beautifulsoup

Can you please suggest a fix? It almost download all the images from imgur pages with one single image not sure why it is not working in this case and how to fix it?

```
elif 'imgur.com' in submission.url and not (submission.url.endswith('gif')
                        or submission.url.endswith('webm')
                        or submission.url.endswith('mp4')
                        or 'all' in submission.url
                        or '#' in submission.url
                        or '/a/' in submission.url):
                html_source = requests.get(submission.url).text # download the image's page
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
                image_url = soup.select('img')[0]['src']
                if image_url.startswith('//'):
                image_url = 'http:' + image_url
                image_id = image_url[image_url.rfind('/') + 1:image_url.rfind('.')]
                try:
                image_file = urllib2.urlopen(image_url, timeout = 5)
                with open('/home/mona/computer_vision/image_retrieval/images/'+ category+ '/'+ 'imgur_'+ datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d-%s') + image_url[-9:], 'wb') as output_image:
                        output_image.write(image_file.read())
                        except urllib2.URLError as e:
                        print(e)
                        continue
```

The error is:

```
[LOG] Done Getting http://i.imgur.com/FoCjtI7.jpg
submission id is: 1alffm
[LOG] Getting url:  http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/217834_10151246341237704_484810759_n.jpg
HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
[LOG] Getting url:  http://imgur.com/xp386
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_images.py", line 67, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "lxml")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 155, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a python shell and try the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
myHTML = "<html><head></heda><body><strong>Hi</strong></body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(myHTML, "lxml")
```

Does that work, or same error? If same error, you're missing lxml. Install it:

```
pip install lxml
```

I'm going through the steps because you indicate that the script works for a good while before crashing, in which case, you can't be missing the parser?

Added by OP:

```
If you are using Python2.7 in Ubuntu/Debian, this worked for me:

$ sudo apt-get build-dep python-lxml
$ sudo pip install lxml 

Test it like:

mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/image_retrieval$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lxml
```

Comment: thanks. Script was working in another machine. I missed to install lxml on this new machine.