# Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested

Tags: django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, vps

Could you please suggest a fix for the problem?
Although 'lxml' and 'html5lib' are installed, and designating the parser, bs4 returns "FeatureNotFound".

I've already referred to [bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986835/bs4-featurenotfound-couldnt-find-a-tree-builder-with-the-features-you-requeste)

All the package installation are basically done through root account.

The code and environment is as followed.
・Sakura VPS
・CentOS7
・python3
・django

```
def Scraper(x):
#setup
query = x
query = query.decode('utf-8')
searchUrl = 'https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=' + query

urls = []

html = requests.get(searchUrl).text
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```